# Need a way to Decrypt the db:provider object for spring configuration before the Spring container initialization

Tags: c#, .net, spring, spring-boot, .net-4.8

I have a .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2 backend codebase with springboot setup, the IApplicationContext is being created Web.config file using the custom configuration section

```
<spring>
  <context type="Spring.Context.Support.XmlApplicationContext, Spring.Core">
    <resource uri="file://services.xml"/>
    <resource uri="assembly://MyAssembly/MyDataAccess/data-access.xml"/>
  </context>
</spring>
```

The data-access.xml file defines various objects being used for instantiation, it also includes the db:provider Object

```
 <db:provider id="PostgreSQL_DbProvider" provider="Npgsql-3.7.7" connectionString="ApplicationName=Hitech;${DbConnectionString}" />
```

The DbConnectionString value is being pulled from another Sample.config file, now we have decided to Encrypt this DbConnectionString in this Sample.config file.This has caused problem as I unable to Decrypt it in the data-access.xml file before the Spring container is instantiated.

I don't want to use CodeConfig to convert all the configurations to code format just to achieve this. Is it possible to create this db:provider object using IDbProvider & DbProviderFactory and Decrypt it there, later use it to instantiate the spring container, I have been reading through it, but because all other configuration are present in xml format, I am not sure how will this IDbProvider object be accessible to the spring container before instantiation.